# Why data doesn't show in activity of android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, baseadapter

Data of MaterialSpinner doesn't show before the user presses the spinner. But Date of MaterialSpinner shows while the user is pressing the spinner. After selected, it doesn't show in MaterialSpinner.

MainActivity.java

```
spn_menu = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_menu);       
spn_menu.setAdapter(new ItemSpinnerAdapter(this, foods));
```

ItemSpinnerAdapter.java

```
public class ItemSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Food> food_list;

    public ItemSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<Food> food_list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.food_list = food_list;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return food_list.size();
    }

    public Food getItem(int position) {
        return food_list.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
        if (tv == null) {
            tv = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, parent, false);
        }
        tv.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Comment: use notifydatasetchanged I think you are setting adapter first and later on data is coming

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: please post your activity code

Comment: check your spinner text color . may be it is transparent or matching your background

Comment: notifydatasetchanged; it doesn't happen.

Comment: Check text color and background color of spinner. If they are same then you know what to do.

Comment: txt color & bg color is ok, not the same.